# checking if browser has a certain extension

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying to build an firefox extension that nudges installation of security-enforcing extensions (like https_everywhere). In that process, I'd like my extension to check if it has https_everywhere installed. 
Is there a programmable way to find out what extensions a user has installed once they enable my extension on their browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [management](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/management)

With the management API you can:

- get information about installed add-ons
- enable/disable add-ons
- uninstall add-ons
  -find out which permission warnings are given for particular add-ons or manifests
- get notifications of add-ons being installed, uninstalled, enabled, or disabled.

Most of these operations require the "management" API permission. Operations that don't provide access to other add-ons don't require this permission.